# Old science fiction story with an alien creature tapping Planck's constant

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

About 50 years ago, I read a science fiction story in a "year's best" anthology.

As I remember it, a guy was visiting a small moon and ran into a scary giant spider-like creature.  He fired a shot, but missed.  They somehow get trapped together.  At some point, one or the other starts rapping out numbers on the (wall?) between them.

Just as the guy realizes that the creature is tapping out Planck's constant and is an intelligent being, the shot he fired, which has circled the tiny moonlet they are on, hits and kills the creature.

Comment: Huh. That would be one heck of a shot.

Answer (score 32):

Possibly ["Moon Duel"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?54104) (1965) by Fritz Leiber, which appeared in [*11th Annual Edition: The Year's Best S-F*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?189209) (1967). The story is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/MerrilEdTheYearsBestSF05/Merril_ed%20-%20The%20Year%27s%20Best%20SF%2011_djvu.txt).

**A guy was visiting a small moon and ran into a scary giant spider-like creature.**

> At the same time I was thinking how if the biped humanoid shape is
> a good one for medium-size creatures on  any planet, why so the spider
> shape is a good one for tiny  creatures and apt to turn up anywhere
> and be copied in robots too.
>
> The top hole in the sixth bubble showed me the stars,  while one half
> of its rim shone white with sunlight.

**The guy realizes that the creature is tapping out Planck's constant and is an intelligent being.**

> Then the number came to me. With the butt of my  Swift I rapped out
> five. No answer. No scratching either. I  rapped out five again.
>
> Then the answer came, ever so faintly. Five knocked  back at me.
>
> Six five five—Planck’s Constant, the invariant quantum  of energy. Oh,
> it should be to the minus 29th power, of  course, but I couldn’t think
> how to rap that and, besides,  the basic integers were all that
> mattered. [...]
>
> We each knew  the other had a suit and a gun (and a lonely hole?) and
> so we knew we were both intelligent and knew math. So  why was our
> rapping so precious?
>
> He raised his gun—I think to rap out one, to start off pi.

**The shot he fired, which has circled the tiny moonlet they are on, hits and kills the creature.**

> But I’ll never be sure, for just then there were two violet  bursts,
> close together, against the fissure wall, quite close  to him.
>
> He started to swing the muzzle of his gun toward me. At  least I think
> he did. He must know violet was the color of  my explosions. I know I
> thought someone on my side was  shooting. And I must have thought he
> was going to shoot  me—because a violet dagger leaped from my Swift’s
> muzzle  and I felt its sharp recoil and then there was a violet globe
> where he was standing and moments later some fragment  twinged lightly
> against my chest—a playful ironic tap.
>
> He was blown apart pretty thoroughly, all his constants  scattered,
> including—I’m sure—Planck’s.

---

Found with the Google query `"year's best" "planck's constant" "science fiction"`.

Comment: Not just an intelligent creature - smart enough to know human *units* for the Planck constant.

Comment: @Adamant And to use base-10 rather than octal, which would be more natural for a spider-like being, assuming it has eight legs ;)

Comment: Also, he's lucky it didn't know the up-to-date value, which starts 6.626 (or 6.582 if he meant the reduced Planck constant in eV*s)

Comment: Actually, what units *are* those, with that 10^(-29)? Not J\*s or eV\*s. And Planck's constant is a quantum of *action*, now that I think about it.

Comment: Microjoule.decaseconds of course

Comment: ... But of course.

Comment: I feel like π would be a better thing to tap out lol. There are people who remember 10000s of digits of pi but no one bothers to remember the same for Planck's constant

Comment: @Neo Darwin: There is nothing to remember, because measurement inaccuracies do not allow us to determine more than a handful of digits. Pi on the other hand is a mathematical construct, which can be calculated to arbitrary precision.

Comment: This is particularly odd given that to identify the other as intelligent, well, first the spacesuit and presence on an alien world would be a big hint, and second tapping anything numeric out, like a fibbonacci sequence or something would do.

Comment: @moopet - Yeah, Fibonnacci would be infinitely better.